# Fortran tool randomly fails to make directory using execute_command_line

Tags: command-line, fortran, mpi

I am using a massively parallel simulation code written in Fortran 90 on our inhouse cluster. The user can specify at which points in time directories with the results are created. The creation of the directory is implemented as follows:

```
call execute_command_line('mkdir -p ./' // adjustl(trim(dirName)),CMDSTAT=CSTAT )

if ((CSTAT > 0) .OR. (CSTAT < 0)) then
    call mpiABORT('mkdir on new time level failed ')
end if
```

Sometimes, the code randomly fails to create the directories. Printing CSTAT tells me that the value is 3, however I have not found any interpretation of this and I do not see why creating this directory works fine for several times, and then at once it suddenly fails. Is there an obvious explanation?

I am using a gnu fortran compiler (mpifort).

Edit: CMSG returns "Invalid command line".

Comment: Are all processes attempting to create the same directory at one time?

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have added that the command above is included in a ```if (IS_MASTER) then``` loop, so only one processor should create the directory.

Comment: You should first print the command you executed when it fails.

Comment: Could you please show the exact code you are using, including the conditionals? Much better would be a short code that demonstrates the problem. Also what OS are you running, and what compiler are you using? The error codes will be implementation dependent.

Comment: Hi, I have printed the command which would be sth like "mkdir -p ./5". OS is OpenSUSE Leap 15.0, compiler is GNU Fortran (SUSE Linux) 7.4.1 20190905

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on our own inhouse cluster where the subroutine "execute_command_line" randomly failed to make a directory.
In my case, the solution was to use:

```
    call system("mkdir mydir")
```

instead of the "execute_command_line" subroutine.

Comment: That sounds very dubious to me. Which compiler was that?

Comment: I had these results with gnu fortran and intel fortran (mpif90 and mpiifort). I spoke with the cluster support about the issue and this was their answer:
"The  'execute_command_line' subroutine is in fact calling 'system' when there is no wait option (i.e. when it is synchronous).". I don't have the reputation to comment thats why wrote this as an answer.

Comment: Yes, execute_command_line calls the C system(3) the same way the system intrinsic does. That's exactly why I am dubious on why there should be any difference. But the code of execute_command_line is more complicated https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgfortran/intrinsics/execute_command_line.c and I cannot claim I understand it all so there can be a lot of stuff hidden.